# How does Spring Cloud AWS get configuration endpoint from logical name of cache cluster?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

I was reading through the documentation on Caching using Spring Cloud AWS
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__caching.html

In the last section it mentions, that it automatically gets the physical name of the cache cluster from its logical name. How does it do that ?
I mean I might have multiple stacks with the same logical name but different physical names.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the source code myself, I found the answer.

Spring Cloud uses the class `StackResourceRegistryDetectingResourceIdResolver` which resolves logical ids to physical resource ids from the stack resources using cloud formation amazon client.

Now, you might wonder how does it get the resources of the stack without the stack name. It does that by using the EC2 instance id which is always available from instance metadata (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html).

The cloud formation client allows you to describe stack resources either by the stack name or physical resource id of any resource present in that stack.

It also has a failover where it returns the stack name by getting the tags of the instance where stack name is present in `aws:cloudformation:stack-name`